# Is reverse relation possible in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not sure if it's name is reverse relation or not but

I have event model which contains  :

```
public function venue()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Venue', 'id','venue_id');
    }
```

So basicly I can access to venue data with event model but also I want to access all event data for spesific venue. I know I can do this with queries etc. but is it possible to do that with relations.

Event Migration

```
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('venue_id');
        $table->decimal('price');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('venue_id')->references('id')->on('venues');
```

Venue Migration

```
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('address');
        $table->text('about');
        $table->timestamps();
```

Event Model

```
public function venue()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Venue', 'id','venue_id');
}
```

Venue Model

```
public function events()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Event::class, 'venue_id','id');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it possible. You can use `belongsTo`

**Venue**

```
public function events() {    
return $this->hasOne(Event::class); 
}
```

**Event**

```
public function venue()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Venue::class);
}
```

Then you can access like below

```
$venue = Venue::with('events')->where('slug',$venue_slug)->get();

foreach($venue as $key=>$value){
 
dd($value->events);

}
```

Comment: I got an error like this "Property [events] does not exist on this collection instance. "

Comment: can you show how you access. .you must define this relation in Venue model

Comment: $venue = Venue::where('slug',$venue_slug)->get();

Comment: $venue = Venue::with('event')->where('slug',$venue_slug)->get();

Comment: then you can access event in loop for example, foreach($venue as $key=>$value){ dd($value->event);}

Comment: if you have any issues then let me know.meanwhile i have updated my answer

Comment: I tried just same as your solution but it returned null

Comment: maybe I should show my migration tables ?

Comment: yes post both tables and also both models

Comment: post entire models .it help me to identify issue

Comment: it sould be events

Comment: check my answer.modfied according to your relationship

Comment: Unfortunetely it still returns null

Comment: yes it iwll return null because your relationship is wrong.so i have updated post .

Comment: is venue has multiple events stored then you have to change hasone to hasMany

Comment: Duuuuude I solved it :) it was like 
public function venue()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Venue::class, 'venue_id','id');
}
I changed it like 
public function venue()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Venue::class, 'id','venue_id');
}

Comment: np :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Since, one venue can have multiple events, you can define a relationship like this in `Venue` Model:

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
}
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer I got an error like this "Property [events] does not exist on this collection instance. "

Comment: Instead of `Venue::with('event')->where('slug',$venue_slug)->get();` can you try, `Venue::where('slug',$venue_slug)->with('event')->get();`? (If the relationship name is events, then please use `events` instead of `event`.

Comment: Unfortunetely it returns null